# Refreshing user's group membership in active directory without log-off/log-on

Tags: active-directory

So, when user logs in to their workstation, they receive SIDs of groups they are members of, and this is used for the length of the session, until logging off.

Is there a way to refresh membership SIDs information without actually having to log off and log on again? I've added myself to a group, but can't log off without interrupting running process that requires these permissions. Don't want to have to go through these steps again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No supported way that I know of.  You MAY be able to use RUNAS to start a command prompt with a new session and specify your same account name again... and that may do it... but I'd be running most (if not all) things that need special permissions as services and/or under service accounts.

Answer (score 5):

- Open Task Manager
- Kill all instances of explorer.exe
- Go to File → "New Task (Run...)"
- Type in `cmd`
- In the command prompt type `RunAs /user:<domain>\<user> explorer.exe`

Done.

Comment: This does not work on my case as I didn't want to interrupt already running process that needed it to begin with.

Comment: This works amazingly well.  After doing it, you may need to run your logon script again to map your drives.

Comment: You can also run `whoami /groups` to see if your session knows about the new group membership.

Answer (score 3):

Is Gpupdate something that would work for you?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490983.aspx

> Refreshes local and Active Directory-based Group Policy settings,
>   including security settings.

```
gpupdate [/target:{computer|user}] [/force] [/wait:value] [/logoff] [/boot]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a new group to show up in `whoami /groups` using a combination of:

1. Run `net use * /delete` to disconnect all active network shares
2. Run `net use \\company.domain.com` to reconnect to active directory domain
3. Lock workstation via start menu
4. Login and run whoami again to verify new group is added

Not sure what step actually cause it to work, but I was able to access a new network share by completing the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

On my domain only works this for a network drive:

```
@echo off
net use M: /d /y
gpupdate /force
net use M: \\10.11.12.233\Archivos /persistent:Yes
explorer.exe M:
```